# 'Multiplying' arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-structures, matrix-multiplication, convolution

First off, I didn't know what to put as title, since the question is not easy to formulate shortly.

I need to convolve a matrix-valued function (k) with a vector-valued function (X), each of which is defined on R^3. I need to to this in MATLAB, so naturally I will do the discretized version. I plan on representing k and X by 5- and 4-dimensional arrays, respectively. This seems a bit heavy though. Do you know if there are any better ways to do it?

Instead of doing the convolution directly, I will go to Fourier space by `fft`'ing both k and X, pad with zeros, multiply them and then use `ifft`. That should produce the same result and run much, much faster.

My question here is whether there is any way to multiply these arrays/matrices easily? I.e. is there any way to do `k(i,j,k,:,:)*X(i,j,k,:)` for all i,j,k, without using three nested loops?

Answer (score 1):

Do you *need* to discretize? Matlab is perfectly capable of taking functions as input and output. For examples, you could define a convolution function:

```
>> convolve = @(fm,fv) @(x) fm(x) * fv(x); %fm matrix valued, fv vector valued
```

and define some matrix-valued and vector-valued functions (this assumes the input is a column vector)

```
>> f = @(x) [x x x];
>> g = @(x) cos(x);
```

now their convolution:

```
>> h = convolve(f,g);
```

and try applying it to a vector:

```
>> h([1;2;3])
ans =
   -0.8658
   -1.7317
   -2.5975
```

You get the same answer as if you did the operation manually:

```
>> f([1;2;3]) * g([1;2;3])
ans =
   -0.8658
   -1.7317
   -2.5975
```

Comment: I'm afraid I have to, since what I actually need to do is to convolve a matrix-valued function with a vector-valued stochastic process. I don't know, but I'm guessing stochastic processes are not easy to deal with in MATLAB without discretizing.

Answer (score 0):

You perform element-by-element operation by using . together with the operator of choice. For example:

```
Element-by-element multiplication: .* 
Element-by-element division: ./
```

and so on... is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I know that. What I need is more like element-by-element matrix multiplication, if that makes sense? In the above `k(i,j,k,:,:)` will be a matrix, and `X(i,j,k)` will be a vector. I need to multiply these for each i, j and k.

Comment: I see, have u tried using the conv2 method in MATLAB? Are you sure going to and back from the frequency domain is faster?

Comment: I have not yet tried the loop-solution, which I would need to see if it was actually faster. So no, I actually haven't. However, I tried convolution vs. pointwise multiplication in Fourier space with two 4-dimensional arrays (size 600 x 20 x 20 x 3 or something like that). The convolution took ~5.5 seconds, whereas the multiplication version only took ~0.5 seconds. I suspect the same behavior will show with matrixmultiplaction. Especially when I need to even bigger arrays later on.